# Does react-router-dom v5.2 support React 18, I am having issues with Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

The problem is that when I click in the Genres button in navbar, only the URL changes to `"/genres"` and not the page content. I tried without the `NavLink` it worked well, the same happens with `MovieList` which is default while using `NavLink`.

App.tsx

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Menu />
    <div className="container">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <h3>In theaters</h3>
          <MoviesList movies={movies.inTheaters} />

          <h3>Upcoming Releases</h3>
          <MoviesList movies={movies.upComingReleases} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/genres">
          <IndexGenres />
        </Route>

      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

In the menu component I am using `NavLink`

```
export default function Menu() {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/">
          React Movies
        </NavLink>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink className="nav-link" to="genres">
                Genres
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```